# How to convert "Æàìáûë" to readable cyrillic in Java?

Tags: java, android

I tryed to get `byte` and then convert with Utf-8.

```
 byte ptext[] = first_name.getBytes();
 Log.i("", new String(ptext,"UTF-8"));
```

But it's not working .Sorry for my dumbness. I'm very confused.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve with that code.  Hint: it doesn't make a lot of sense to translate accented Latin characters to cyrillic.

Comment: Why not `Log.i("", first_name)`?

Comment: Hint: Looks like `Windows-1251` bytes interpreted as `ISO-8859-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try {
    String s = new String("Æàìáûë".getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), "Windows-1251");
    Files.write(Paths.get("C:/cyrillic.txt"),
        ("\uFEFF" + s).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Assuming that the editor and compiler are set to UTF-8 to have a correct erroneous string literal.

This treats the characters as single bytes, abusing ISO-8859-1. Then tries the Windows-1251 encoding for Cyrillic (there are others).
This way we have a java String (always in Unicode).
This we'll write to a text file in UTF-8, with a BOM, so Windows Notepad will identify the file as UTF-8.

Writing to any Cyrillic encoding will be no problem.

```
Жамбыл
```

Comment: it's giving me `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets`

Comment: Ah, there Android diverts its libraries. Either use `"UTF-8"` or `org.apache.commons.lang3.CharEncoding.UTF_8`.

Answer (score 2):

Your byte array must have some encoding. The encoding cannot be ASCII if you've got negative values. Once you figure that out, you can convert a set of bytes to a String using:

```
byte[] bytes = {...}
String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); // for UTF-8 encoding
Log.i("value", str);
```

There are a bunch of encodings you can use, look at the Charset class in the [Sun javadocs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html).

Comment: I can't figure out what  the origin encoding is

Answer (score 2):

Seems your original encoding is `Cp1251`:

```
byte ptext[] = first_name.getBytes();
Log.i("", new String(ptext, "Cp1251")); // <- put it here
```

Resulting word is *Жамбыл*.